# Need sample code to call an API

Tags: javascript, api

Actually, we have written javascript code to call the API (which is written in DOTNET). But we got the following error when we run the code:
 "Failed to load https://api.yourmembership.com/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://cgxdev.com' is therefore not allowed access."
   We have contacted the API support team to give access for us to call the API. But we couldn't get the access till now.
   Is there any way to call the API without getting access to call?

Here is the javascript code we have written:

```
// Create a request variable and assign a new XMLHttpRequest object to it.
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Open a new connection, using the GET request on the URL endpoint
request.open('GET', 'https://api.yourmembership.com?apikey=', true);

request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://cgxdev.com');

request.withCredentials = true;

request.onload = function () {
    console.log(request.responseText);
};

request.send();
console.log(request.status);
console.log(request.statusText);
```

Comment: yes, proxy through your own server ... server to server requires no access control - though, my guess is your javascript code is probably doing something wrong - only a guess, but I'd bet I'm right

Comment: Can I get any document to call API from server to server Please?

Comment: sure - google search engine is good for looking up language documentation - include `proxy` in your search - good luck

Comment: Are you writting the API or is it a third-party API like google-maps API or something?

Comment: It is a third-party API which is written in dot net. My client has an account in it and we need to call the API to display the database in it.

Comment: @  Jaromanda X : Do you mean using an APP like postman to call API? Sorry If I am wrong. If so, I do not want to use any app. I need to write a sample code either in javascript/jquery/PHP to call the API without getting access as I have specified already. Is there any way?

Comment: @SuriyaKarthikeyan Did you solve the issue?  I am receiving the same error from YM's API.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll attempt to an answer eventhough I don't know if you are writing this API yourself or if you are using a third-party one.

I think your JS code is not the issue here. You need to enable [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) in your API configuration.

I'm not a .NET developer but your problem is very similar to the one i had when I was building RoR API from scratch. Enabling CORS request in my back-end and allowing all origin solved my issue. But if you have only a few client for that API, it should be possible only those domain. [Here is some documention that could be helpful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) for .NET.
Specially [this part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#scope-rules-for-enablecors) where they show you how to configure allowed domains.

PS: Again, mind that I never code in .NET
and If that not mistaken with this answer then the your line of code:

```
request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://cgxdev.com');
```

is redundant (You can delete it).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And the problem is, we cannot configure the API as we are using the third party API. And we have tried contacting the support team and they are not helping us for the configuration.

Comment: Hence I am asking is there any other way to call the API without editing the configuration in the API code which is written in dotnet since we cannot edit it.

Comment: Unfortunally, I don't think there is nothing you can do without their support. I would advise to read their documentation carefully if they have one. If they don't you should consider to change.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response.